# Why is ravana still worshipped in a few places till today despite being the demon king?

Tags: ramayana, gods, ravana, india

I have seen in films, heard tales about how in south India many people worship ravana, surely they must be following a different folklore version which edifies ravana but isn't Ramayana an universally accepted epic which villainizes ravana ?

Knowing that what prompts a few to worship him ?

Comment: Ravana Mandir, Bisrakh, Greater Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India.

There is a huge Shivalinga in Kakinada, Andhra Pradesh, India. supposedly installed by Ravana himself, with a statue of Ravana near by. Both Shivalinga and Ravana are worshiped by the fishermen community there.

Thousands of Kanyakubja Brahmins of the village Ravangram of Netaran, in the Vidisha District of Madhya Pradesh, perform daily puja (worship) in the Ravan temple and offer naivedyam / bhog (a ritual of sacrifice to the Gods).-From wikipedia.

Comment: *Centuries ago King Shiv Shankar built a Ravana temple at Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh. The Ravana temple is opened once in a year, on Dashehra Day, to perform puja for the welfare of Ravana.

Comment: From wiki again-Ravana was born to a great sage Vishrava (or Vesamuni), and his wife, the daitya princess Kaikeshi. People of Bisrakh village in Uttar Pradesh claim that Bisrakh was named after Vishrava, and Ravana was born there.[9].So infact  Ravan is worshiped more  in north india than in the south.Maybe because he was born there.

Comment: So the same people celebrate dussehra ? :-P

Comment: If you are asking me,how can i know?

Comment: He was born in a brahmin family. He was the great follower of Shiva, a great scholar, a capable ruler and a maestro of the veena. His ten heads represent his knowledge of the six shastras and the four Vedas. 
also depicted as the author of the Ravana Samhita, a book on Hindu astrology and book Arka Prakasham; book on Siddha medicine and treatment . Ravana possessed a thorough knowledge of Siddha,"The Oldest traditional treatment system" and political science. He is said to have possessed the nectar of immortality, which was stored inside his belly, thanks to a celestial boon by Brahma.

Comment: Do you know Shivatandava strotram is made by Ravana?

Comment: "Rakshasa","asura" etc. don't mean anything negative. Starting with Amar Chita katha and North Indian TV serials - Rakshasas are depicted as dark-skinned people with lots of facial hair and generally ruffianly characteristics. calling people "monkeys" seems to be racist also. What Rama and Lakshmana are supposed to have done in the forest seems to be Aryan genocide of adivasis. Just like Karna has lots of following among modern day Hindus - the other side of the ramayana story needs to be told also. Ravana had lots of admirable qualities and it is no wonder that he is worshiped.

Comment: " seems to be Aryan genocide of adivasis." And that's your conclusion based on depiction of asuras in TV serials.! And the fact that Aryan theory has been long debunked has no bearing?! Your answer is not only incorrect and irrelevant, it is based on misinformation.

Comment: I thought I commented on this Q at the time. My comments were deleted!? No astika Hindu worships ravana

Comment: OK - 'arya genocide".  To depict forest dwellers as cannibals (IIRC) and the horrific tale about Surpanakha are really embarrassing.

Comment: What is embarrassing? It is part of the Ramayana which is itihaasa -literally "it happened thus". You cannot change history. We can only learn from it.

Comment: It is clear you know nothing about either of them or their story. Even a rakshasa said " ramo vigrahavan dharmaH" .

Comment: @SK I would gladly take that bet (assuming I don't incur any sin from gambling).  The Pramanya of our scriptures can be proven, see Adhyaya 1 Pada 1 of the Purva Mimamsa Sutras.

Comment: *thumbsup* @KeshavSrinivasan . SK- Take it up with Keshav.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> No where in Ramayana, written by Valmiki, the writer of the epic,  Rama was mentioned as God. Neither Ravana.
>
> Though demon king Ravana is the prime  antagonist character in the epic Ramayana, yet most of the people are not aware of his background, his conquests  and his erudite knowledge.
>
> He is considered as the most revered devotee of Lord Shiva. An Accomplished Scholar, great musician.
>
> Ravana's grandfather, the sage Pulastya, was one of the ten Prajapatis or mind-born sons of Brahma and one of the Saptarishi (Seven Great Sages Rishi)
>
> Ravana performed an intense penance (or tapasya) to Brahma, lasting several years. During his penance, Ravana chopped off his head 10 times as a sacrifice to appease him. Each time he sliced his head off a new head arose, thus enabling him to continue his penance. At last, Brahma, pleased with his austerity, appeared after his 10th decapitation and offered him a boon. Ravana asked for immortality, which Brahma refused to give, but gave him the celestial nectar of immortality. The nectar of immortality, stored under his navel, dictated that he could not be vanquished for as long as it lasted.
>
> His abilities now truly awe-inspiring, **Ravana proceeded on a series of campaigns, conquering humans, celestials and other demons.** Conquering the netherworld completely, he left his brother Ahiravana as king. He became supreme overlord of all Asuras in the three worlds, making an alliance with the Nivatakavachas and Kalakeyas, two clans he was unable to subdue. Conquering several kingdoms of the human world, he performed the suitable sacrifices and was crowned Emperor. Ravana defeated Indra and the gods, Surya, Varuna and Yama.
>   Kubera at one point chastised Ravana for his cruelty and greed, greatly angering him. Proceeding to the heavens, Ravana fought and defeated the devas, singling out his brother for particular humiliation. By force he gained command over the devas, celestials, and the serpent races. At the time of the Ramayana, set several years later, Ravana is shown as dominating all human and divine races – so much so that he can command the sun's rising and setting.
>
> Ravana was a great practitioner of statecraft(the skillful management of state affairs; statesmanship.). When Lord Rama killed Ravana, who was on his last breath, Rama instructed his brother Lakshmana to go to Ravana and learn the art of statecraft and diplomacy from the dying demon king.
>
> It was Ravana and his brother Kumbhakarana, who performed penance, got miraculous powers  from Lord Brahma and drove out Kuber to occupy the golden kingdom of Lanka.
>
> There are several temples in India where Ravana is worshipped and associated with Lord Shiva at some places. Temples related with Ravana in India are Ravana Mandir Bisrakh,Koteshwar Temple Gujarat,Vidisha Ravangram Temple and Murudeshwara Temple has Ravana Statue, Koneswaram temple of Sri Lanka is one of the most famous Ravana temple in the world.
>
> As a conclusion: The heroism of the hero is proportional to the greatness of the villain. And One Must Never Forget That Ego Kills.

[5 Life Lessons From Ravana](http://www.mensxp.com/work-life/balance-work-and-life/24025-5-life-lessons-from-ravana.html)

[Ramayana (Hindu epic): Is Ravana a hero or is he a villain?](https://www.quora.com/Ramayana-Hindu-epic/Is-Ravana-a-hero-or-is-he-a-villain-Why)

[Ravana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana#Tapasya_to_Brahma)

Comment: If you copied your answer from other places (which is ok), you need to use [blockquotes](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes). Also, when you quote something from somewhere you need to verify authenticity of the content before posting it here. (See [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/48/2995))

Comment: @sv I have posted the links at bottom.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but you still need to use blockquotes when you are quoting others (blogs, Wikipedia etc.)

Comment: But in tv series Devon ke dev mahadev, they showed that ravan built golden kingdom for Lord Shiva as he used to live in bare mountains but lord shiva refused to live there and asked ravan to live in it instead

Comment: Rama is mentioned as God in the Ramayana written by Valmiki and Ravana is said as cruel and personal blogs are not considered authentic sources. The one you quoted is a personal blog.

Comment: Well after the Ramayana era was over the victors (Rama, Lakshmana, Seetha, Hanuman, Bibhishana) were portrayed as gods and the losers (Ravan, Kombhakarna, Meghnath, Atikaya, Makaraksha) were portrayed as demons.

Comment: devon ke dev mahadev is merely a tv serial it has so many factual errors its just very well made compared to the ones that you see nowadays

Answer (score 0):

Only an ignorant person can worship Ravana.

Ravana had usurped Kubera's throne and Pushpaka-vimana, and kidnapped Sita by deceit.

Here are some of the lesser-known character traits of Ravana:

Ravana had raped 3 women viz. Rambha, the daughter-in-law of Kubera [Ref: Mahabharata 3.278]; Rtuvarman's wife Madanamanjari [Ref: Puranic Encyclopedia page 646]; and Rishi Udanga’s daughter Malati as per folklore.

Ravana had molested Rishi Kushadhwaja’s daughter Vedavati [Ref: Ramayana 7.17]; harassed Dvaipayana's sister; dragged Atri's wife by her hair; humiliated Agni's wife Svaha; tried kidnapping Brihaspati's daughter Sulekha [Ref: Puranic Encyclopedia page 646]; and even cast his evil eye on Goddess Lakshmi [Ref: Ramayana 7.28].

Ravana had tried humiliating God Brahma's daughter Punjika [Ref: Puranic Encyclopedia page 646]. This shows total lack of respect for the God who had given him so many boons.

Ravana had kidnapped innumerable celestial ladies [Narasimha Purana 47.28].

Ravana held Rishi Vasishtha captive for not teaching him the Veda; insulted Devarishi Narada, Rishi Ashtavakra, Rishi Dattatreya, Rishi Mandavya and Rishi Maudgalya [Ref: Puranic Encyclopedia page 646].

God Shiva had granted Ravana unequalled strength, but he did not have faith in his benefactor. He shamelessly went back to lift Mt Kailasha. God Shiva then deemed that Ravana’s end was near [Ref: Shiva Purana Kotirudra-samhita 28.60-72].

To meet his selfish lustful desires, he sacrificed the lives of his brother Kumbhakarna, his sons, Mareecha and millions of other Rakshasa.

Source: 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani pages 15-16